# how to get the control of the UI Element Clicked in a external application

Tags: c#, .net, controls, hook, handles

How can i get the control (and possibly its text value) of a control which was clicked in another third party application (its not a .net or wpf application for which there are answers which did not solve my problem)

I can get the click event in my app (using the global hooks as mentioned [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx))  i want the control/handle of that particular UI Element

Example : I have opened Notepad and when i click on File Menu, i want the control of that File button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the documentation for [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using the `WH_CALLWNDPROC` param.  This will let you intercept messages in Notepad window procedure.  You'll need to figure out which messages get generated from clicking the menu items in Notepad, you can use Spy++ for that.  But there is no real control for the File button, it is part of a menu.